# How to read TCP window size with windows sockets?

Tags: c, windows, sockets, tcp

Right now im working on a light cliente/server application written in C to check some problems with many computers sending data with TCP to a server through a switch.

I need to read some of the flow control variables, like for example the window size, number of retransmitted packets, etc.

In linux i do it with getsockopt, method i've read here: http://linuxgazette.net/136/pfeiffer.html but i can't find an equivalent method in the windows socket api.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Vista or above then it looks like `GetPerTcpConnectionEStats()` might give you what you need. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb485738(VS.85).aspx

However, I've never used it and the docs look like they could be better...